# How to properly use indexes in mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm new to mongoose and mangodb. Recently, I've noticed that my GCP compute engine instance(Ubuntu) sometimes runs at 100% CPU load. When I run the `htop` command, `mongod.conf` is always at the top of the list. I guess this is because I'm not using any index in my Mongoose schema. Could someone give me clarification on the following questions?

1. Should I add indexes for all query fields, if I use queries with multiple filters? (I use more than 8 query fields)
2. Does the order of query filters affect performance?
3. If I add indexes to my mongoose schema, does that build indexes for existing documents?
4. Should I add indexes for sort fields such as `updatedAt` or `createdAt`?
5. Is it necessary to use indexes on documents that have only less than 4 fields?
6. How can I find which query is taking too much time?

Thanks

Comment: you can read here more about MongoDB indexes 
https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/indexes/
mongoose just uses the native MongoDB functions so everything here is applies to mongoose

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. => NO (use [compound index](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/index-compound/) to combine multiple fields for filters , if it used multiple times in query .  use only important fields for index )
2. => YES (if you added index field first it will be faster)
3. => NO (you need to manually execute command `db.collectionName.createIndex({ fieldName: 1 })` Or Create index using MongoDB Compass)
4. => NO
5. => IT DEPENDS , if this query required to execute multiple time then you can create [Single Field Index](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/index-single/) else not required
6. => Use [MongoDB Compass](https://www.mongodb.com/products/compass) , **Explain Plan** Tab to check query performance

[image]

Comment: If I'm building an index with the command line, Should I change anything in my nodejs code?

Comment: if you are using mongoose then add `index:true` in mongoose model .